# Mongoose error handling with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I'm using mongoose with native ES6 promises for database management in my Nodejs, REST API.

I'm having trouble finding best practices with error handling. I have a section of code that looks like this:

```
Cities.findOne({'id': someid}).then((city) => {
  if (!city) throw 'No city found';
  //modify city.embedded.dynamic.field
  return city.save();
}).then((city) => {
  if (!city) throw 'City not saved';
  res.send(city);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Is it necessary for me to check if the return of the `city.save()` is undefined? Or will an error in the save be caught in the catch?

It's unclear in the docs whether or not `save()` could return `undefined` like how mongoose queries sometimes do.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I'm using `findOne` and manually modifying schedule because mongoose can't model the schema it's dynamic as well as embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose promises use the `callback(error, result){}` mechanism that follows the exposed crud functions, such as `newElement.save( function( err, result){} )`. If any error occurs, the promise is rejected, and this is logic.

Answer (score 1):

`findOne()` return a promise. It is `resolved` when the result is returned, be it empty or not. It is `rejected` when an error occurred. An empty result to any `find()` will be `null`, not `undefined`.

You will get a `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of null]` if the element you're trying to save doesn't not exist.

You can however makes this simpler :

```
return Cities.findByIdAndUpdate(city._id, {$set:city}, {new: true} ).exec()
             .then( (city) => { res.send(city) } )
```

setting the option `new` to `true` makes the function returns the element **after** update, and not before

Comment: The `findByIdAndUpdate` would work nicely but I can't use that :( (added edit in my question). The part I'm concerned about is if it's possible for model#save to fail and still have it's promise `resolved`.